# Snowflake, select tables count error: Information schema query returned too much data

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I use database Snowflake. Schema has more 15000 tables. And I tried to get information about tables count in my current schema by following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(T.table_name) as tnum FROM information_schema.TABLES T WHERE 
 T.table_schema = 'MYSCHEMA' 
 AND T.TABLE_CATALOG = 'MYDB' 
 AND T.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
```

And get the following error:
**"Information schema query returned too much data.  Please repeat the query with more selective predicates."**

Do you know how to solve this kind of error?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) as tnum FROM information_schema.TABLES T WHERE 
 T.table_schema = 'MYSCHEMA' 
 AND T.TABLE_CATALOG = 'MYDB' 
 AND T.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'

Try with this query statement.

Comment: Your query is trying to retrieve too much information from information_schema.  Snowflake limits this request for performance reasons:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema.html#general-usage-notes.  Leveraging SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLES is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the same query on Account usage schema and it should work

```js
SELECT COUNT(T.table_name) as tnum FROM snowflake.account_usage.TABLES T WHERE 
 T.table_schema = 'MYSCHEMA' 
 AND T.TABLE_CATALOG = 'MYDB' 
 AND T.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Comment: unfortunately, snowflake.account_usage does not exist

Comment: snowflake.account_usage is available in all Snowflake deployments.  You just need to request access to it from your ACCOUNTADMIN to the role you are using.

Comment: thank you, but I cannot use any role ACCOUNTADMIN, It should be worked with all available role, role can be unset in the connection properties

Comment: In that case, you will have to limit the data retrieved as Information Schema query directly query from metadata and will not allow it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as tnum FROM information_schema.TABLES T WHERE  
T.table_schema = 'MYSCHEMA'   AND T.TABLE_CATALOG = 'MYDB'   AND
T.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Use this query code and try once.

Answer (score 0):

```
   // count of all the tables in the given database and schema. (Excludes dropped tables)
   SELECT count(T.table_name)
   FROM   snowflake.account_usage.tables T
   WHERE  table_catalog = 'DB_NAME'
   AND    table_schema = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
   AND    table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
   AND    deleted IS NULL // This filters the dropped table
```